# c++ : Friend function was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, declaration, friend, name-lookup

I'm not able to call a friend function in my main program. Moreover, I have three files, my `main.cpp` program, a `foobar.h` and a `foobar.cpp` for the functions of my class. When I try to call the `friend myClass* foobarfunction` in my main.cpp program, I get the following error:

> [Error] 'MyFunction' was not declared in this scope.

I'm compiling the program in the Dev C++ Environment, using GCC 4.9.2.

My main program where I call the `foobarfunction` is the following, where `headers.h` contains all my header files.

```
#include "headers.h"

a = MyFunction(something1, something2);
```

Then the `foobar.h` file is:

```
class MyClass {
   public:
      MyClass();
      virtual ~MyClass();

   private:
      friend MyClass* MyFunction(const int a, const int* b=0, const double c=1., const double d=2.);
};
```

Also my `foobar.cpp` program contains the MyFunction program as follows:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass() {...}
MyClass::~MyClass() {...}

MyClass* MyFunction(const int a, const int* b, const double c, const double d) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

Is it possible that the version of the GCC compiler creates the error?
Please let me know if I need to post more segments of my code. Thanks.

PS: I have tried also compiling the code on linux GCC version g++ 11.2.0 and on Windows with newer g++ version but I'm getting a lot of errors `friend declaration of '' specifies default arguments and isn't a difinition`, that's why I'm trying with an older compiler. This program was writen in 2010.

Comment: Side note: [Link to a MUCH more recent version of devcpp](https://github.com/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp)

Comment: You `#include "headers.h"`, but `MyFunction` is declared in foobar.h.

Comment: I think a [mre] is in order here. We like minimal, but if minimal can't reproduce the same error, too much was cut away.

Comment: A friend declaration is normally visible only to the class where it is declared. If you want to call it elsewhere, you need to provide another declaration at the file/namespace scope.

Comment: Friend function declarations may not have default arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The friend declaration

```
friend MyClass* MyFunction(const int a, const int* b=0, const double c=1., const double d=2.);
```

is not visible outside the class where it is declared until its declaration will appear outside the class.

From the C++ 17 Standard (10.3.1.2 Namespace member definitions)

> 3 If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class,
> function, class template or function template97 the friend is a member
> of the innermost enclosing namespace. **The friend declaration does not
> by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup (6.4.1) or
> qualified lookup (6.4.3).** [ Note: The name of the friend will be
> visible in its namespace if a matching declaration is provided at
> namespace scope (either before or after the class definition granting
> friendship). — end note ]

You need to include a declaration of the function outside the class in the header `foobar.h`.

Also the default arguments may be present in the friend function declaration that is its definition and is only the function declaration in the translation unit.

From the C++ 17 Standard (11.3.6 Default arguments)

> 4. ... If a friend declaration specifies a default argument expression, that
>    declaration shall be a definition and shall be the only declaration of
>    the function or function template in the translation unit.

Comment: So do I have to call first the class in the main program? I have tried that and still I get an error.

Comment: @ilp The function main shall see the friend function declaration outside the class definition.